# Could please someone give me a right correction for this query? with Union

Tags: union

with T1_CTE as select ad_date, spend, impressions, reach, clicks, leads, value, 'facebook_ads'
as media_source
from facebok_ads_basic_daiy fabd
union ad_date, spend, impressions, reach, clicks, leads, value 'google_ads'
from google_ads_basic_daily gabd)
select media_source, sum(spend) as SUM_SPEND, sum(impressions), sum(clicks)
from T1_CTE
group by ad_date, media_source;

Combine data from different tables using the union operation
**But query won't work**